# Reuse calculated table variable within DAX formula

Tags: caching, powerbi, dax

I have the following DAX formula for a measure, and it works fine.

```
Gross Area = 
var as_on = LASTDATE('Calendar'[Date]) 
var all_latest_dates =
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        VALUES('Unit Revision'[Unit Id]),
        "Last Event", CALCULATE(
                            MAX('Unit Revision'[Event Date]),
                            'Unit Revision'[Event Date] <= as_on
                        )
    )
var unit_latest_dates = TREATAS(all_latest_dates, 'Unit Revision'[Unit Id], 'Unit Revision'[Event Date])
RETURN
CALCULATE( SUM('Unit Revision'[Gross Area]), unit_latest_dates )
```

I need to calculate more metrics using a similar logic, where the DAX formula is the same until the RETURN statement, and just the column name within the final CALCULATE( SUM() ) differs.

I then need to add all these measures to a Matrix. In such as case, will the variable calculation of the unit_latest_dates table be calculated for every DAX measure, or will it be cached? To ensure it is cached, is it possible to reuse the initial set of DAX code within a calculated table measure or something, just like how we can reuse a scalar measure in another measure?

I can't use this in a Calculated Table, as the calculation changes based on changes in the Calendar Table Date slicer.

Comment: If you have a basic version of the measure that makes a calculate(sum()), then you can use Calculation Group to not reproducing code. Powerbi is a SSAS Tabular version, here we have StoreEngine and FormulaEngine query -> storeEngine query is cached. This you can check inside DaxStudio ServerTiming feature.

https://www.sqlbi.com/tv/creating-custom-groups-using-calculation-items-unplugged-24/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be cached as long as DAX Engine can understand that a similar query was executed earlier and it didn't involve a CALLBACKDATAID and was executed only by Storage Engine and not Formula Engine, try to use DAX Studio and see if it is doing that or not.